# Определене времени обработки MySql запросов в .net приложении?

Tags: mysql, windows, .net, ado.net

Можно ли в Windows при помощи стандартных счетчиков производительности определить время выполнения запроса в базе данных MySql, т.е. время ожидания между вызовом IDbCommand.ExecuteReader и получением данных?

Comment: А может лучше проводить измерения напрямую в `mysql`? Иначе рискуете тестировать скорость вашего интернета

Comment: В конечном нужно показать соотношение времени работы программы в целом и ожидания ответа от базы данных. В общем увидеть, что время отработки алгоритмов программы значительно меньше, чем время отработки запросов в базе данных.

Answer (score 1):

Стандартный коннектор поддерживает всего два счетчика - `HardProcedureQueries` и `HardProcedureQueries`, в категории `.NET Data Provider for MySQL`.

Счетчики влючаются опцией `Use Performance Monitor=true` в connection string (или ее ализами - `UsePerformanceMonitor`, `userperfmon`, `perfmon`).

Но оба стандартных счетчика типа `NumberOfItems`, поэтому время выполнения на их основе получить нельзя. Максимум - количество запросов в секунду за некоторый интервал времени.